# How to index a list of points for faster searches of nearby points?

Tags: python, search, indexing, point

For a list of (x, y) points, I am trying to find the nearby points for each point.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from math import sqrt
from random import randint

# Generate a list of random (x, y) points
points = [(randint(0, 100), randint(0, 100)) for _ in range(1000)]

def is_nearby(point_a, point_b, max_distance=5):
    """Two points are nearby if their Euclidean distance is less than max_distance"""
    distance = sqrt((point_b[0] - point_a[0])**2 + (point_b[1] - point_a[1])**2)
    return distance < max_distance

# For each point, find nearby points that are within a radius of 5
nearby_points = defaultdict(list)
for point in points:
    for neighbour in points:
        if point != neighbour:
            if is_nearby(point, neighbour):
                nearby_points[point].append(neighbour)
```

Is there any way I can index `points` to make the above search faster? I feel there must be some faster way than O(len(points)**2).

Edit: the points in general could be floats, not just ints

Comment: if your grid is just 100*100 you could arrange your points inside that grid. this way you could drastically reduce the search space.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22082/how-can-i-use-r-tree-to-find-points-within-a-distance-in-spatialite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a version with a fixed grid where each gridpoint holds the number of samples that are there.

the search can then be reduced to just the space around the point in question.

```
from random import randint
import math

N = 100
N_SAMPLES = 1000

# create the grid
grd = [[0 for _ in range(N)] for __ in range(N)]

# set the number of points at a given gridpoint
for _ in range(N_SAMPLES):
    grd[randint(0, 99)][randint(0, 99)] += 1

def find_neighbours(grid, point, distance):

    # this will be: (x, y): number of points there
    points = {}

    for x in range(point[0]-distance, point[0]+distance):
        if x < 0 or x > N-1:
            continue
        for y in range(point[1]-distance, point[1]+distance):
            if y < 0 or y > N-1:
                continue
            dst = math.hypot(point[0]-x, point[1]-y)
            if dst > distance:
                continue
            if grd[x][y] > 0:
                points[(x, y)] = grd[x][y]
    return points

print(find_neighbours(grid=grd, point=(45, 36), distance=5))
# -> {(44, 37): 1, (45, 33): 1, ...}
# meadning: there is one neighbour at (44, 37) etc...
```

for further optimzation: the tests for `x` and `y` could be precalculated for a given gridsize - the `math.hypot(point[0]-x, point[1]-y)` would not have to be done then for every point.

and it may be a good idea to replace the grid with a `numpy` array.

---

**UPDATE**

if your points are `float`s you can still create an `int` grid to reduce the search space:

```
from random import uniform
from collections import defaultdict
import math

class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x_int(self):
        return int(self.x)

    @property
    def y_int(self):
        return int(self.y)

    def __str__(self):
        fmt = '''{0.__class__.__name__}(x={0.x:5.2f}, y={0.y:5.2f})'''
        return fmt.format(self)

N = 100
MIN = 0
MAX = N-1

N_SAMPLES = 1000


# create the grid
grd = [[[] for _ in range(N)] for __ in range(N)]

# set the number of points at a given gridpoint
for _ in range(N_SAMPLES):
    p = Point(x=uniform(MIN, MAX), y=uniform(MIN, MAX))
    grd[p.x_int][p.y_int].append(p)


def find_neighbours(grid, point, distance):

    # this will be: (x_int, y_int): list of points
    points = defaultdict(list)

    # need to cast a slightly bigger net on the upper end of the range;
    # int() rounds down
    for x in range(point[0]-distance, point[0]+distance+1):
        if x < 0 or x > N-1:
            continue
        for y in range(point[1]-distance, point[1]+distance+1):
            if y < 0 or y > N-1:
                continue
            dst = math.hypot(point[0]-x, point[1]-y)
            if dst > distance + 1:  # account for rounding... is +1 enough?
                continue
            for pt in grd[x][y]:
                if math.hypot(pt.x-x, pt.y-y) <= distance:
                    points[(x, y)].append(pt)
    return points

res = find_neighbours(grid=grd, point=(45, 36), distance=5)

for int_point, points in res.items():
    print(int_point)
    for point in points:
        print('  ', point)
```

the output looks something like this:

```
(44, 36)
   Point(x=44.03, y=36.93)
(41, 36)
   Point(x=41.91, y=36.55)
   Point(x=41.73, y=36.53)
   Point(x=41.56, y=36.88)
...
```

for convenience `Points` is now a class. may not be necessary though...

depending on how dense or sparse your points are you could also represent the grid as a dictionary pointing to a list or `Points`...

also the `find_neighbours` function accepts a starting `point` consisting of `int`s only in that version. this might also be refined.

and there is  much room for improvement: the range of the `y` axis can be restricted using trigonometry. and for the points way inside the circle there is no need for an individual check; detailed checking only needs to be done close to the outer rim of the circle.

Comment: Thanks - what about if the points are floats instead of ints? This method would only work if we round the floats into ints

Comment: I think tweaking your above approach would work. Instead of searching on a fixed grid, search between `bisect_left((point[0] +/- distance, point[1] +/- distance), points)`